# Transactions per second in a socket with python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I have a program in Python and I have a connection with a socket.

I am using a semaphore to have the control use  `n` threads.

But the problem is when I execute the python program, I calculate the transactions per second and I have 6,14 transactions per second (average). But I need a maximum of 5 transactions per second for each thread.

I am trying with a sleep in the semaphore, but it is not working for me.

or how can i control that?

How can I control the transactions per second in a socket for thread with Python?.

Comment: What do you mean by transactions per second? You call `socket.send()` 5 times a second?
Also can I ask why you're using multiple threads? Is there more than one socket? Or are you having multiple threads send different / class specific data over the same socket.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to gather whatever metrics it is you think are relevant?  Your question is incredibly hard to understand at present ...